# Google auth page is not working in my current project. I am attaching the image current problem and the eroor message

Tags: python, json, flask, google-oauth, google-cloud-console

[image: Error screen]

I am trying to make a project which uses google plus api from google cloud console that is used for authentication, but as soon as I click on the id for the authentication it shows this error. I dont know what to do next its frustrating.

I tried some code changes that chat gpt said. I even did pip install --upgrade google-auth google-auth-oauthlib google-auth-httplib2
to upgrade google auth but it didnt work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I thought the google plus api was gone by now.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check what time your machine is running at make sure its in sync with NTP.

## detailed explanation of the error message

[image]

The way Oauth works is that the authorization server returns to you an authorization code, this code is generated when the user consents to your application accessing their data.

Your system has a very short window in which to use this code.  Its under five minutes.  In your case if you read the message it clearly states that you have used the token to early.  and that you should check your computers clock

If the token was generated at 12:00 it would mean that it can be used probably between 12:00 and 12:05.  What do you think the error would be if you tried to use it at say 11:59?  Well you would be using it to early.

Check your clock.

Comment: How to check. ?

Comment: Look at the clock on your computer My guess you are running fast

Comment: I dont think my computer has time issues as its automatic.

Comment: Check my edit where I explain to you what the error message means.

Comment: Yeah did made some clock changes in my computer. I turned on automatic time zone mode and it worked for some time but after I opened it after several hours it gave the same error.

Comment: This really isnt a programming issue, this is an issue with your computer.  Fix your time, you cant use the codes to early as I have told you.

Comment: Thank you for your help...Have a goofd day